# Are θ/þ/th distinct in Etruscan transcription?

Tags: alphabet, orthography, etruscan

While trying to answer an etymological question, I was looking through several different online resources about Etruscan vocabulary. Annoyingly, although these resources use *mostly* the same transcription system, there are a few significant differences.

Specifically, some sources use «th ph kh» for   , while others use Greek «θ φ χ» (sometimes substituting Latin «þ» and «x»). And some seem to mix the two styles: Wikipedia "Etruscan language" mentions both *zilaχ* and *zilath* as words for "praetor".

When a source uses both digraphs and Greek letters for the Etruscan aspirates, is there a reason for this? For instance, do inscriptions distinguish between  «θ» and  «th»? (If so, are there theories on what the distinction could mean phonologically?) Or is it just inconsistent editorial preference, like macrons on Latin vowels?

Comment:    is what you can find in the actual Etruscan texts but since it is time-consuming and typographically challenging, they are transliterated as Greek θ φ χ - cf. "Etruskische Buchstaben, die im lateinischen Alphabet fehlen, aber im griechischen Musteralphabet vorhanden waren, naemlich Theta, Chi und Phi transkribiert man griechlich" (Etruskische Texte, v. 1, p. 20).

Comment: a nice table https://books.google.com/books?id=aPEENAEp938C&lpg=PA229&dq=cambridge%20encyclopedia%20of%20ancient%20languages&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching through Glen Gordon's [database of attested Etruscan word forms](https://sites.google.com/site/paleoglot/Home/09417289.xml?attredirects=0), I haven't found any instances of transcribed *th* (tau + eta), even as variants or hapaxes. This leads me to believe that it's just Wikipedia's inconsistent editing again, occasionally substituting digraphs for non-Latin letters without rhyme or reason.